# how to draw a Mathjax table using array with row span?

Tags: html, latex, mathjax, tex

Since mathjax does not support latex table, I have to take advantage of array to implement a table as such:

```
\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline 
\end{array}
\]
```

This piece of code shows like:

[image: table]

But this method doesn't work with \multicolumn and \multirow, therefore I cannot draw an embedded table with MathJax.

What I want is a table like:

[image: table with column/row span]

How to do it? Plz help.

Comment: Why don't you just use an `html` table? Why do you specifically want the table in `MathJax`?

Comment: What @koder613 wrote - use HTML tables. Also, MathJax currently does not support colspan and rowspan in tabular environments as indirectly mentioned in https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/mathml.html#supported-mathml-tags. So you'd have to hackaround with nested arrays.

Comment: Definitely agreed, go for an html table and fill the cells with math expressions within MathJax math delimiters :)